# System.InvalidOperationException: Already closed after updating from iTextSharp 5.3.3 to 5.4.2

Tags: exception, pdf-generation, itext, document, corruption

I'm getting a `System.InvalidOperationException: Already closed` exception after updating [iTextSharp NuGet package](https://nuget.org/packages/itextsharp/) from v. 5.3.3 to 5.4.2.

This happens when I call:

```
Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
.
.
.

doc.Close(); // Document is already closed hence the exception
```

It's important to note that this code was working flawlessly with `iTextSharp 5.3.3`.

I commented that line and the `PDF` got generated but then `iTextSharp` started outputting corrupted `PDF` files that could not be opened by Adobe Reader nor Windows 8 built in PDF reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playing with the code in Visual Studio and taking advantage of IntelliSense I looked at the various possible methods on the `Document` object. I saw that there is an additional method called `CloseDocument()`, so I changed this line:

```
doc.Close();
```

to

```
doc.CloseDocument();
```

and guess what? The thing started working again. No more exceptions. Awesome!

Hope it helps anyone that might encounter this same issue in the future...

---

Well well well... after trying different input options I started getting the exception again...

I was explicitly calling:

```
pdfReader.Close();
```

inside an `AppendToDocument` method. This was happening before calling `doc.Close();`. Just commented the above line and the exception went away.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
private void ceratepdf()
    {
        using (FileStream msReport = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~") + "/App_Data/" + DateTime.Now.Ticks + ".pdf", FileMode.Create))
        {
            //step 1
            Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 2f, 2f, 10f, 15f);

            PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, msReport);
            PdfPCell cell;
            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(4);
            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Incident Details"));

            cell.Colspan = 4;

            cell.HorizontalAlignment = 1; //0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right
            cell.VerticalAlignment = 1;

            table.AddCell(cell);
            doc.Open();
            doc.Add(table);
            doc.Close();
        }
    }
```